# How to clear all data is jsGrid?

Tags: jsgrid

There are many answers on how to clear the data from the similarly-named [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=15), but I can't find any way to clear data from [jsGrid](http://js-grid.com). I just want to delete all rows and reset the grid to its default, with no rows.

I do see a [Batch Delete method here](http://js-grid.com/demos/), but it works with checkboxes and conditionals and I'm not seeing how to simply delete all rows unconditionally.

Comment: This is tagged as jsgrid but you are asking about jqGrid.

Comment: No, Jamo, it's jsgrid. http://js-grid.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set `data` option to empty array:

```
$("jsGrid").jsGrid("option", "data", []);
```

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that seems to work for me is

```
$("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
    controller: {
        loadData: function(filter) {
            return [];
        }
    }
});
```

We need to return an empty array or object.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What worked without implications for me was

```
$(".jsgrid-grid-body").children().remove();
```

if I wanted to keep the headers to indicate that there simply aren't any rows, and

```
$("#jsGrid").children().remove();
```

if I wanted to remove the whole grid.